# Just how much am I over-complicating this code (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to achieve are 2 seperate blockquotes, each with different properties such as background, hight and width   ( I know that I don't need to use the style tag, instead I should link, I know, don't mention it)

```
<div class="banana">
              <blockquote>
              <style>
        .banana blockquote{background: yellow; height: 50px; width: 100px;}
              </style>
              please work
   <p>I have created a weapon which will destroy all life in Azeroth. `</p>`

              <p> With such genieuss, he battled the enemy for control. </p>
              <p> But he lost. Rip </p>
              </blockquote>
              </div>

              <div class="monkey">
              <blockquote>
              <style>
              .monkey blockquote{ background: red; height: 5px; width: 5px; }
              </style>
              <p> This better work </p>
              </blockquote>
              </div>
```

Comment: why do you use style tags on not css?

Comment: And..., what do you need exactly?

Comment: You should start by reading the basics of html to begin with.

Comment: You have to place `style` tags in the `header` tags not in your `div`

Comment: @ThomasRollet You actually don't need to use `<style>` tags in the `head` or `header`. They can be placed directly within `div` elements like OP has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the `<div>` tags since you're just defining a class. Add the classes to the `<blockquote>` itself to clean things up a bit.

```css
.banana {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
}
.monkey {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Banana Blockquote -->
<blockquote class="banana">
  please work
  <p>I have created a weapon which will destroy all life in Azeroth.</p>
  <p>With such genieuss, he battled the enemy for control.</p>
  <p>But he lost. Rip</p>
</blockquote>

<!-- Monkey Blockquote -->
<blockquote class="monkey">
  <p>This better work</p>
</blockquote>
```